# CSS translate3d performance problems on mobile devices with big DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, owl-carousel

I'm using OwlCarousel 1.3.3 on a website pretty much like the sync example from the owl website (http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/one.html):

```
var owlconfig = {
  singleItem: true,
  navigation: false,
  pagination: false,
  afterAction: syncCarousels
};


$('.image-gallery').owlCarousel(owlconfig);
```

The syncCarousels doesn't have any magic in it and it doesn't cause the lag, because it's still happening when I take that method out.

The HTML of the carousel (after initialising the JS):

```
<div class="image-gallery owl-carousel owl-theme">
  <div class="owl-wrapper-outer">
    <div class="owl-wrapper">
        <div class="owl-item" style="width: 300px;">
            <a href="images/image.jpg" class="image-gallery__image">
                <img src="images/image.jpg" alt="Image" itemprop="image">
        <span class="button">
            <span class="btn__inner">Detail</span>
        </span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="owl-item" style="width: 300px;">
            <a href="images/image.jpg" class="image-gallery__image">
                <img src="images/image.jpg" alt="Image" itemprop="image">
        <span class="button">
            <span class="btn__inner">Detail</span>
        </span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="owl-item" style="width: 300px;">
            <a href="images/image.jpg" class="image-gallery__image">
                <img src="images/image.jpg" alt="Image" itemprop="image">
        <span class="button">
            <span class="btn__inner">Detail</span>
        </span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="owl-item" style="width: 300px;">
            <a href="images/image.jpg" class="image-gallery__image">
                <img src="images/image.jpg" alt="Image" itemprop="image">
        <span class="button">
            <span class="btn__inner">Detail</span>
        </span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the desktop version, everything works fine, but if I test it on an iPhone or iPad, the swipe feels extremely laggy. On DragEnd, it stops for like 500ms, before anything happens.

The page where the carousel is embedded has a lot of difference html markup, text and images basically. If I remove some of that markup, the owlCarousel performance improves, but thats not a solution.

How could the performance be improved? Event the "noSupport3d" option of owl which uses jQuery animate performs better.

Comment: can we have a jsfiddle for this... so that we can find out easy solution...

Comment: I'd love to provide a jsfiddle, but I can't make it work unfortunately. the application is pretty complex and when I try to simplify it to only show the gallery, the problem suddenly disappears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out, here's the solution for everyone stumbling upon a similar problem:

A big amount of DOM elements affect the performance of transitions, that's why the slider worked perfectly in a lightweight html page but had performance issues in a bigger page.

What I did now to increase performance of my slider was adding `transform: translateZ(0px)` to the parent element of the one being translated.

**Attention**: Using translate3D does not make this code redundant. I'm now using translate3D for the sliding effect AND translateZ(0px) for the parent container of the sliding one - this did the trick.